# Marking answer on downvoted question

Tags: support, down-votes, accepted-answer

I want to know if we can mark an answer as accepted answer if the question gets down voted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can select an answer as accepted regardless of the current votes on the question.

A question which may not be well received for whatever reason doesn't provide any detriment to a good answer which solves the problem or otherwise is the answer to the question being asked.